# Concatenate all .mp4 files in a folder using ffmpeg

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to resize a bunch of videos and save them as: 1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4... in the same folder.

Next, I'd like to use another ffmpeg command to concatenate all the videos in order, and save the final video in the same folder.

**What I've Tried:**

`run('ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "{}" -c copy "{}\\{}.mp4"'.format(clips, location, today))`

where 'clips' is a txt file containing absolute paths to each clip, formatted as "file path/to/file.mp4", location is the absolute path of the output directory, and 'today' is the file name such as '22 December'.

**The Issue I'm Encountering:**

```
[concat @ 000001850996df80] Impossible to open 'D:Reddit'
D:\Reddit Compilation Bot\Videos\Perfectly Cut Screams\22 December\paths.txt: No such file or directory
```

And yes, I've checked all my file paths to see if they were missing the backslash as the error suggests, but I couldn't find any issues. Further, I copied and pasted the path in the error message directory into  Windows Run and it opened without issue.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code working for me

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mp4
```

where input.txt looks like

```
file './vid1.mp4'
file './vid2.mp4'
And so on...
```

Only condition in this sample is that all the videos should be formatted in same way

Comment: are you using relative or absolute paths? @Darpan5552

Comment: @Coski I am using relative paths